# pass observable from one view model to another in knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

Within a view I have a button which navigates to another view 'addWork'.
I want to pass an observable from the view model to the view model associated with the addWork view.
I already have addWork within the constructor for the view model, I'm just unsure what else to do.

The url action on the ko.applybinding is as follows, this work fine, I just need to amend so I'm passing the observable.

```
"@Url.Action("AddWork", "Work")")
```

The button is bound to this function:

```
   self.AddWork = function () {
            window.location.href = addWork;
        }
```

Comment: This needs some further explanation. Are you trying to pass an observable from your server-side controller to a new html view? Given the `@Url.Action` I assume you're using asp.net MVC?

Comment: Yes, to both your questions.  I'm fairly new to MVC / MVVM and trying to pick it up as I go along.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. An observable is purely a javascript concept and typically won't survive being sent to the server and back. Can you explain why you need the observable and not just the observable's contents?

Comment: I guess the contents would do, to be honest I wasn't entirely sure if it should have been the observable or not.  All I'm trying to achieve is passing an id from one view to another

Comment: If you know the ID you can put it into your @Url.Action statement like `Url.Action("AddWork", "Work", new { id = myID });`

Comment: thanks, if you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observable is purely a javascript concept and typically won't survive being sent to the server and back. You would be better off sending just the contents of the observable instead of the observable itself.

If you just need to send an ID then with asp.net MVC you can put it into your @Url.Action statement like `Url.Action("AddWork", "Work", new { id = myID });`